# Order on count of associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have got a little further in a problem I have been having, I have three models Trader/Location/Service....a Trader HABTM Locations and a Trader has many Services.

For a Location instance I am trying to return all of its traders in descending order of the count of services.  I have managed to get 2 queries to actually return results:

```
l = Location.find_by_post_code("G1")
l.traders.includes(:services).order('COUNT(services.id) DESC').group("services.id", "traders.id").references(:services)
```

and

```
l = Location.find_by_post_code("G1")
l.traders.includes(:services).select("services.id, count(services.id) as count").group("services.id", "traders.id").references(:services)
```

Both of which return results but neither are actually ordering on the Service count at all, what am I doing wrong =(

Comment: could you post the result of l.traders.includes(:services).select("services.id, count(services.id) as count").group("services.id", "traders.id").references(:services).to_sql

Comment: Could you also show the returned data from the db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l.traders.includes(:services).select("services.id, count(services.id) as count").group("services.id").order("count DESC")
```

What database are you using?

Comment: Postgresql, your answer is close but I realised I cannot use services.id in select and group.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = Location.find_by_post_code("G1")
l.traders.joins(:services).select("traders.id, traders.name, count(services.id) as count").group("traders.id").order("count DESC")
```